Fill Between Polar Graph Part 2
I have been looking for about 30 minutes and can't figure out how to shade the where area S is (both sides). I can fill the entire plot, but can't figure out how to use a soft clip to highlight the small oval.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

    
        \pagestyle{fancy}
            \fancyhead[L]{Polar Curves on Calc BC}
            \fancyhead[R]{Name:\enspace\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}}
            \fancyfoot[C]{BC Calculus}
            \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
            \fancyfoot[L]{Created By: Mr. Bennett}
                \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
                \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
                \newcommand*{\myprime}{^{\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
                \newcommand*{\dprime}{^{\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
                \newcommand*{\trprime}{^{\prime\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}   
        
        \addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.49998pt}
        
%For Polar      
\pgfplotsset{
    interpret as polar/.style={
            x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{cos(rawx)*rawy},
            y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{sin(rawx)*rawy}
        }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            axis lines=center,
            axis equal image,
            enlargelimits=true,
            xlabel={\(x\)},
            ylabel={\(y\)},
        ]
    \addplot[name path=A,
            thick,
            domain=0:360,
            samples=360,
            smooth,
            interpret as polar
        ] 
        (x,{1+2*sin(x)});
       \node at (.1,.7){\(S\)};
       \path[name path=xaxis] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
       \addplot[blue,opacity=0.5] fill between[of=A and xaxis,
       soft clip={domain=7*pi/6:11*pi/6}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{Center}
                
        
\end{document}

'''

      


I toyed around with the soft clip domain, but kept seeing the colour appear elsewhere. Here is a "dirty" hack. I hope it is helpful:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{Polar Curves on Calc BC}
\fancyhead[R]{Name:\enspace\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}}
\fancyfoot[C]{BC Calculus}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{Created By: Mr. Bennett}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\newcommand*{\myprime}{^{\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
\newcommand*{\dprime}{^{\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
\newcommand*{\trprime}{^{\prime\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}   
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.49998pt}

%For Polar      
\pgfplotsset{
    interpret as polar/.style={
        x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{cos(rawx)*rawy},
        y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{sin(rawx)*rawy}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    axis equal image,
    enlargelimits=true,
    xlabel={\(x\)},
    ylabel={\(y\)},
]
    \addplot[name path=A,
        thick,
        domain=0:360,
        samples=360,
        smooth,
        interpret as polar
    ] 
    (x,{1+2*sin(x)});
    \node at (.1,.7){\(S\)};
    \path[name path=xaxis] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \addplot[blue,opacity=0.5] fill between[
        of=A and xaxis,
        soft clip={domain=0:pi/8}
    ]; %%% Colours the right half
    \addplot[blue,opacity=0.5] fill between[
        of=A and xaxis,
        soft clip={domain=0:-pi/8}
    ]; %%% Colours the left half
    \addplot[white,opacity=1] fill between[
        of=A and xaxis,
        soft clip={domain=0:0.2}
    ];  %%% dirty hack
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{Center}

\end{document}

This produces the output:


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}        
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
interpret as polar/.style={
x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{cos(rawx)*rawy},
y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{sin(rawx)*rawy}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
axis equal image,
enlargelimits=true,
xlabel={\(x\)}, ylabel={\(y\)},
]
\addplot[
fill=blue, opacity=0.5,
domain=210:330,
samples=121,
smooth,
interpret as polar,
] 
(x,{1+2*sin(x)});
\addplot[
thick,
domain=0:360,
samples=361,
smooth,
interpret as polar,
] 
(x,{1+2*sin(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: If you do not like solving for the relevant domain, you can also use even odd rule with a \clip like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}        
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
interpret as polar/.style={
x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{cos(rawx)*rawy},
y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{sin(rawx)*rawy}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
axis equal image,
enlargelimits=true,
xlabel={\(x\)}, ylabel={\(y\)},
]
\begin{scope}
\clip (-0.4,0) rectangle (0.4,1.1);
\addplot[
fill=blue, even odd rule, opacity=0.5,
domain=0:360,
samples=361,
smooth,
interpret as polar,
] 
(x,{1+2*sin(x)}) (0.5,0) rectangle (-0.5,1.5);
\end{scope}
\addplot[
thick,
domain=0:360,
samples=361,
smooth,
interpret as polar,
] 
(x,{1+2*sin(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

